# Verificar se um ficheiro existe na máquina remota via FTP em PHP

Tags: php, arquivo, ftp

Como é que posso verificar se um ficheiro existe na máquina remota utilizando PHP através das funções de [FTP](http://pt2.php.net/ftp) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> de forma a agir em conformidade?

```
<?php
$ficheiro = 'public_html/banana.xml';

$id_ligacao = ftp_connect($servidor_ftp);

$login = ftp_login($id_ligacao, $utilizador, $password);

// verificar se ficheiro existe
if (ficheiro_existe($ficheiro)) { // função para ilustrar o conceito
  echo "existe!";
} else {
  echo "não existe!";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: A resposta rápida é "use ftp_size()". A resposta longa está [abaixo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8090/4186), com considerações sobre alternativas, incluindo sugestão de cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que usando a função file_exists pode resolver o seu problema de forma mais simples:

```
if(file_exists('ftp://usuario:senha@servidor.com.br:porta/caminho/do/arquivo')) ...
```

Comment: Efectivamente parece bem simples, mas estarei sujeito a falso negativo? Ou seja, se existir um problema a estabelecer ligação e/ou problema com credenciais de acesso vai-me indicar que o ficheiro não existe, certo?

Comment: Sim, se você errar a senha, nunca vai saber se existe mesmo. Não experimentei, mas penso que em caso de erro, vai retornar FALSE, mas a variável $php_errormsg vai ter uma mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 2):

A melhor sugestão (e aparentemente a [mais votada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4852812/287948)) é `ftp_size`, já que não abre o arquivo nem carrega a listagem inteira da sua pasta.

---

Eu não testei nem comparei restrições, o `fopen` também deve funcionar elegantemente, evitando o "falso negativo" de `file_exists` (ver comentário do @Zuul sobre resposta do @mlemos) [quando analisamos  erros](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Em seguida temos a sugestão do ftp_nlist, que "mata a formiga com elefante", mas pode ter a sua array cacheada e então reusada em outras verificações (!), ou seja, pode ser uma solução ótima em certos casos.

- Use [`ftp_size()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-size.php), que retorna -1 quando não existe;
- Use [`fopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), ex. `fopen("ftp://user:password@example.com/somefile.txt", "r")` mas requer [avaliação do erro (!)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) para não ser "falso negativo";
- Use [`ftp_nlist()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php), idealmente com solução de cache abaixo.

---

### `ftp_file_exists()` com cache da ultima pasta

O uso das funções especializadas em FTP requer certo preparo. Aqui copio uma parte da resposta (também bem aprovada!) de https://stackoverflow.com/a/9568577/287948

É uma versão mais rebuscada da resposta do @PauloRodrigues, onde acrescentei o preparo comentado e o cache sugerido antes.

```
  function ftp_file_exists(
      $file,                     // o arquivo que se procura
      $path = "/SERVER_FOLDER/", //pasta onde ele está
      $ftp_server = "ftp.example.com",
      $ftp_user = "ftpserver_username", $ftp_senha = "ftpserver_password",
      $useCache = 1
  ) {

      static $cache_ftp_nlist=array();
      static $cache_assinatura='';

      $nova_assinatura = "$ftp_server$path";
      if (!$useCache || $nova_assinatura!=$cache_assinatura) {
          $useCache = 0;
          $nova_assinatura=$cache_assinatura;
           // setup da conexão
           $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Não pode conectar em $ftp_server");
           ftp_login($conn_id,$ftp_user,$ftp_senha);
           $cache_ftp_nlist = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $path);
           if ($cache_ftp_nlist===FALSE) die("erro no ftp_nlist");
      }

// verificando se o arquivo existe:
        $check_file_exist = $path.$file;
        if (in_array($check_file_exist, $cache_ftp_nlist)) {
            echo "EXISTE, achei: ".$check_file_exist." na pasta : ".$path;
        } else {
            echo $check_file_exist." não está na pasta : ".$path;   
        };
        // para debug: var_dump($cache_ftp_nlist);
// lembrar de fechar a conexão ftp
        if (!$useCache) ftp_close($conn_id);
        } //func
  // CUIDADO: o cache não pode ser usado se a pasta está sendo alterada!
```

Funções utilizadas:

1. Login  [ftp_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php)
2. Sugestão do @PauloRodrigues para pegar o arquivo remoto via [ftp_nlist](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php)
3. ... mesma sugestão de [in_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) para ver se o arquivo está presente.

Comment: Uma vez que a tua sugestão é o `ftp_size` e mesma parece ser uma boa ideia, se puderes colocar em português a parte que fala sobre isso seria bom. Quanto à segunda parte da tua resposta, dado ser igual ao que o Paulo Rodrigues já havia respondido, penso que pode ser retirada.

Comment: **Nota:** Se gostaste da solução no @mlemos podes votar na mesma para manifestar a tua opinião na resposta dele ;)

Comment: Bom dia! Você foi muito rápido, estou acrescentando solucao do cache... Ok, agora pode comentar :-)

Answer (score 0):

Que tal com **[ftp_nlist](http://php.net/ftp_nlist)**?

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($id_ligacao, "public_html");

if (in_array($ficheiro, $contents)) {
    // existe
} else {
    // não existe
}
```

Comment: A solução parece boa, mas quando lidamos com uma directoria onde existem por exemplo 1000+ ficheiros, não irão existir problemas de performance?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar ftp_mlsd que irá retornar a lista de arquivos e diretórios. Depois basta percorrer essa lista e verificar se o diretório desejado está contido nela.