# Como faço para verificar se um arquivo html foi gerado no ftp e se foi gerado, abrir ele no navegador?

Tags: php, html, ftp

Possuo um formulário, após preencher e enviar o formulário, é gerado um arquivo `csv` com os dados do formulário, o arquivo é enviado para uma aplicação no servidor onde faz os devidos cálculos e gera um arquivo `html` em uma pasta no `ftp`, gostaria de saber como faço para verificar se o arquivo `html` foi gerado e se foi gerado, abrir ele no navegador na mesma aba em que enviei o formulário.

O arquivo `csv` e o arquivo `html` vão ter o mesmo nome.

```
while (!file_exists("$diretorio/$filehtm")) {
      sleep(1);
      header("Location: Link_Para_Ser_Redirecionado.htm");    
    }
```

Comment: já deu uma pesquisada no google ou aqui mesmo no site?
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8041/verificar-se-um-ficheiro-existe-na-m%C3%A1quina-remota-via-ftp-em-php

Comment: Sim, dei uma pesquisada no google e aqui no site e fiz alguns testes, mas nada efetivo

Comment: Poste o que já tentou, mais fácil ajudarmos em corrigir algo que já começou do que uma solução completa

Comment: Editei a postagem com o Loop que estou tendo dificuldade, ele não está sendo redirecionado para o arquivo htm quando ele é gerado no ftp

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, de qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Legal Ian, depois poste a solução como uma resposta para ficar registrado caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

```
while (!file_exists(ftp://usuario:senha@ftp.servidor.com/diretorio/arquivo)) sleep(1); //O sleep serve como intervalo no loop
    header("Location: http://link_para_ser_redirecionado.com");
```